# Waiting for the query to complete (never completes)

Tags: postgresql, postgis, common-table-expression, spatial

When i run this query stucks at 'Waiting for the query to complete'

```
with
    cte1 as (
        select
            id as c,
            ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lo, la), 4326) as u_t1
        from t1
        ),
    cte2 as (
        select
            t2.a1 as c,
            st_union(t2.way) as c1
            from t2
            group by c
        ),
    cte3 as(
            select sum (t3.a2) as sum1              
                from cte1, cte2, t3
                where st_intersects(cte1.u_t1, cte2.c1)
                group by cte2.c1
        )
 select 
    cte3.sum1
    cte2.c  
    from cte3,  cte2
```

The propose of the query is `SUM` a `INT` column with a `ST_INTERSECTS` restriction. The attributes of the st_intersect are deduced in the ct1 and ct2. I guess it could take some time but the problem is that the query never completes.

Any idea why?

Thanks!

Comment: By not using the ANSI join syntax, you are creating potentially huge Cartesian products.  Please spend a few minutes here:  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am studying on my own although sometimes I need help, but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is probably here:

```
cte3 as(
        select sum (t3.a2) as sum1              
            from cte1, cte2, t3
            where st_intersects(cte1.u_t1, cte2.c1)
            group by cte2.c1
    )
```

You join three tables, but there is only a join condition between `cte1` and `cte2`. As a consequence, you will get every possible combination of rows from that join with rows from `t3` in the result set (a Cartesian product). This is probably large and the cause of your problem.

To avoid that problem, get into the habit of using the standard join syntax:

```
FROM cte1
   JOIN cte2 ON st_intersects(cte1.u_t1, cte2.c1)
   JOIN t3 ON ...
```

Then you cannot forget a join condition, because it is a syntax error to have no `ON` clause.